# Two way data binding and sending data from html to variables in ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass data from `html form` to the `variables` (`email and password`) in function `doRegister()`, when form submits. But this two-way data binding pops up following errors.

**Errors:**

**In html:** Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{email}}=$event] in "path to the html document"

**In TS file:** Can't resolve all parameters for RegisterComponent in "path to the .ts file"

**1. HTML FILE**

```
<p class="lead">Already a member? Please <a routerLink="/login">log in</a> instead</p>
<form (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
<div role="alert" *ngIf="formError" class="alert">{{ formError }}</div>
      <p>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="{{email}}" required>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="{{password}}" required>

      </p>
      <p>
          <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
      </p>
  </form>
```

**2 .TS file**

```
import { User, UserRegister } from './../user';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Loc8rDataService } from '../loc8r-data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private Authentication: AuthenticationService) { }
    
      
      ngOnInit() {
      }
        
    
      formError: string ='';
    
        public onRegisterSubmit(): void {
    
        this.doRegister();
       
          }
    
        private doRegister(): void {
    
          let uEmail = '';
    let uPassword = '';
    const userreg: UserRegister = {email: uEmail, password: uPassword };
    
        this.Authentication.register(userreg)
        .catch((message: string) => this.formError = message);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Just remove the curlies {{email}} => email

Answer (score 1):

See the following for added description. But you are just using incorrect syntax. See below.

https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel

You don't need the braces

```
 <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="{{password}}" required>
```

should be

```
 <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
```

Be sure that you have declared any variable that you are using in your html template inside your .ts file as a public field or your html file will not be able to use it.

Comment: now prompts different error, `Identifier 'password' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member`, does it has anything to do with the error in the TS file that I have mentioned?

Comment: Because you reference `let uPassword = '';` instead of `password`. Your .ts file must declare the variables that you use inside your html file. I'll update the answer for clarity

Answer (score 1):

> Identifier 'password' is not defined. The component declaration,
> template variable declarations, and element references do not contain
> such a member

because it unable to find those two variables in TS file, use this:

HTML file .

```
<p class="lead">Already a member? Please <a routerLink="/login">log in</a> instead</p>
    <form (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
    <div role="alert" *ngIf="formError" class="alert">{{ formError }}</div>
          <p>
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
          </p>
          <p>
              <label>Password:</label>
              <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
    
          </p>
          <p>
              <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
          </p>
      </form>
```

.TS file

```
import { User, UserRegister } from './../user';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Loc8rDataService } from '../loc8r-data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    
      constructor(private Authentication: AuthenticationService) { }
    
      
      ngOnInit() {
      }
      password:string='';
      email:string='';
        
    
      formError: string ='';
    
        public onRegisterSubmit(): void {
    
        this.doRegister();
       
          }
    
        private doRegister(): void {
    
          let uEmail = '';
    let uPassword = '';
    const userreg: UserRegister = {email: uEmail, password: uPassword };
    
        this.Authentication.register(userreg)
        .catch((message: string) => this.formError = message);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: prompts an error: `Can't resolve all parameters for RegisterComponent path/register/register.component.ts`